# Cut particular parts from a line in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am new at shell script. I have a file containing some records like this:

```
aaaa,-1,0
bbbb,2,3
cccc,-5,-10
dddd,0,100
```

I want to write a script that will make the list look like this:

```
1 aaaa -1 0
2 bbbb  2 3
3 cccc -5 -10
4 dddd  0 100
```

Can someone help me regarding this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk '{gsub(/,/," ");print NR,$0}'  file
```

if you want to have nicer output, try this:

```
awk '{gsub(/,/," ");print NR,$0}'  file|column -t
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "aaaa,-1,0
bbbb,2,3
cccc,-5,-10                                            
dddd,0,100"|awk '{gsub(/,/," ");print NR,$0}'          
1 aaaa -1 0
2 bbbb 2 3
3 cccc -5 -10
4 dddd 0 100
```

with `|column -t`:

```
kent$  echo "aaaa,-1,0
bbbb,2,3
cccc,-5,-10                                            
dddd,0,100"|awk '{gsub(/,/," ");print NR,$0}'|column -t
1  aaaa  -1  0
2  bbbb  2   3
3  cccc  -5  -10
4  dddd  0   100
```